# How to lock portait orientation on mobiles and landscape for tablets using css or JS?

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am modifying a wordpress theme using elementor, but I cannot modify mobile and tablet landscape in preview.

Because of that, I am forced to block orientation in landscape mode for mobile and portrait for tablets because it looks bad.

I have contacted the developers of the theme and they have given me a valid solution in css. I provided the code, but when the keyboard opens, the page breaks.

Any simple solution in JavaScript or css?

I would also like to add if you know how to include an image of turning your device.

Thank you for your attention, greetings and thanks to all.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jUUi.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

welcome to stack overflow.

You can use javascript to do that, by using the `screen` property.

```
screen.orientation.lock("landscape-secondary");
```

This will lock your screen on landscape mode.
In case you wish to unlock you can use:

```
screen.orientation.unlock();
```

Tip for posting: It's a good practice to not upload image links but instead paste the code you've tried on the post so that is searchable for users who might have the same problem in the future.

Try that and see if works.
Good luck

Comment: Thanks for answering, where do I put this code? I found this: screen.orientation.lock ("natural"); for mobile portraits and tablet landscapes. I think it's similar but I don't know where to insert it.

Comment: that's  javascript code where you should be executing when the page loads.

Comment: In my case i have a dedicated JavaScript section inside wordpress menu > theme options > JS > introduced the code: screen.orientation.lock("landscape-secondary"); but still doesn´t work.

Comment: I have tried putting the code that you have given me inside the JS editor that comes with the theme.

Comment: I have tried putting screen.orientation.lock("landscape-secondary");  in js editor but nothing happens.